# How to get AWS command line interface to work in cygwin

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, cygwin, command-line-interface, credentials

I installed the AWS command line interface on my Windows 7 box, and it worked immediately when I called commands from a DOS shell.

But DOS, the worst language ever invented, is hideous for any serious scripting.  So, I would like to to use the AWS CLI from bash via cygwin.

In my case, the installed AWS CLI is the Windows version.  In principle, that should not be a problem because Windows commands are executable from cygwin.  ([cygwin includes your Windows environmental variables](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html), such as PATH, in its own environment.)

Unfortunately, when I first tried to execute an AWS CLI command from cygwin/bash, I got an error:

```
$ aws s3 cp code.tgz s3://xyz/
upload failed: .\code.tgz to s3://xyz/code.tgz
Unable to locate credentials
```

This error is likely because the AWS CLI is looking in the wrong directory for the `credentials` file.  On Windows, it expects that file to be in `%UserProfile%.aws` and in unix in `~/.aws`.

One hack work around is that in my home directory I created a new file named `config_credentials` which contains a union of the contents of that directory's files `config` and `credentials`.  I then made a new Windows System env var named `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` whose value is the path to `config_credentials`.  Success: AWS CLI commands issued from cygwin now work.

I am wondering if there is a better solution?

I am curious why AWS CLI initially failed to search in the correct home directory for the `config` and `credentials` files.  I also wonder if there is a way to correct that (this would eliminate the need for the `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` env var).

Comment: Would you be interested in PowerShell as an alternative?  AWS has made a native PS CLI: http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/

Comment: Only as a last resort.  My company wants to limit how many languages we use (continuity of maintenance is a concern), and bash is used in several places (especially on servers) whereas PowerShell has never been used.  There would have to be a really compelling use case to justify a new language.

Comment: Ah yes, DOS, that well-known language.

Comment: or a cygwin alternative, docker.  I personally would never run cygwin.  Too many pitfalls, too crufty.  No offense intended of course to those users to whom it speaks

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem.  I got around it by installing a new copy of AWSCLI within Cygwin.  You first need to install the "curl" and "python" Cygwin packages, then you can install AWSCLI as follows:

```
$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
$ pip install awscli
```

If you're running bash, and you've previously executed the Windows AWS command line, you need to clear the cached path as follows:

```
$ hash -d aws
```

"aws --version" will then look similar to this:

```
aws-cli/1.8.1 Python/2.7.10 CYGWIN_NT-10.0/2.2.1(0.289/5/3)
```

as opposed to the Windows command line output, which looks similar to this:

```
aws-cli/1.8.1 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8
```

I'm now able to do "aws configure" under Cygwin, and everything works as it should.

Comment: Worked, however I had to use the cygwin installed copy of python, rather than the one via the windows msi installer.

Comment: Where does it install? I must have a bad path because even though pip installs `aws` cannot be found.

Comment: Justin, are you sure you're using the Cygwin Python rather than the Windows one, as Adrian pointed out?  I just reinstalled it, and:
"which python" gives me "/usr/bin/python",
"which aws" gives "/usr/bin/aws" and
"aws --version" gives "aws-cli/1.11.66 Python/2.7.13 CYGWIN_NT-10.0/2.7.0(0.306/5/3) botocore/1.5.29".

Comment: @CraigHeath When I run `which python` it returns the python version stored in the Windows Anaconda directory: i.e. C:\Users\rchase\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe.  How to I go about changing this?  Does this mean we cannot use the anaconda version of python??

Answer (score 8):

After a LOT of time spent on this, I found a solution that works.

The primary issue is that the cygwin didn't come with python installed, and doesn't know where to find the existing Windows Anaconda version on your machine. This can be verified by running which python from within cygwin - it couldn't find where python is saved. Note that this can be confusing because running pip install awscli likely doesn't throw an error message. Cygwin actually installs awscli in the Window's Anaconda installation of Python (I find this odd since we didn't run conda install awscli).

HOWEVER, rather than try to point cygwin to the already installed version of Anaconda python on your machine it will save you a ton of headache to just install a cygwin-specific instance of python.  The steps to do so are documented here: http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Awscli_in_cygwin)

1. `pip uninstall awscli`
2. `wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg`
3. `install apt-cyg /bin`
4. `apt-cyg install python`
5. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
6. `python get-pip.py`
7. `pip install awscli`

...Note, however, that the first command `pip uninstall awscli` "hung up" for me.  So just escape out of it using `quit()` and continue with the others in order.

You can check that everything worked if you run `which python` in cygwin and it points to the cygin version (i.e. /usr/bin/python , as opposed to:  /users/.../Anaconda2/).

Additionally, if you happen to be asking this in conjunction with watching the setup video for the fast.ai course (http://course.fast.ai/lessons/aws.html), then the next step is ***CRITICAL*** for Windows users: when you download all the shell scripts from Github setup folder (https://github.com/fastai/courses/tree/master/setup), Windows automatically adds CRLF line terminators!  Therefore, in cygwin, run the following commands to remove these line endings:

1. `apt-cyg install dos2unix`
2. `dos2unix setup_p2.sh`
3. `dos2unix setup_instance.sh`
4. then finally, `bash setup_p2.sh`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Also following fast.ai tutorial here. For me this did not help at first because I already had Python 3 installed. `which python` showed up correctly but `which pip` did not- and that was my problem. I ended up uninstalling all of my instances of python (except anaconda) and deleting the folder with the package cache in my C drive (the python folder). After that I was able to run get-pip, verify I was calling it, and finally install awscli. What a headache!

Comment: even I have the same problem, is there a way I can do this without deleting all instance of python because I am using that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I used aws configure from DOS cmd window to create the cfg files (config and credentials) and tested them with a sample aws cmd (in DOS window). Then I copied Users\.aws folder to spot where cygwin thinks the user home folders are (in my case c:\cygwin64\home\). I then used TextPad to convert the line endings (use file>save-as; select unix line endings; make sure the files don't get renamed x.txt). Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to:

```
# Run Cygwin64 Terminal by right-clicking on the icon and selecting "Run as Administrator"
pip3.7 install awscli
aws configure
```

Once my AWS credentials had been configured I could run awscli commands on Cygwin where the latter had been launched normally, i.e. as a non-Administrator user.

Earlier I attempted the same steps but I launched Cygwin as non-Adminstrator and the awscli installation through pip didn't take. I didn't save the error messages, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that jumps through all the Microsoft hoops; it's tedious to do for setup, but works very cleanly once you're actually using the AWS CLI.  You don't need to do anything weird in Cygwin until the very end, but you may need Windows admin privs depending on your computer policies.

1. Install the Windows version of the AWS CLI.  (It's currently distributed as an `.msi` installer, so likely needs admin privs to install to `%PROGRAMFILES%`.)
2. Launch a good ol' CMD.EXE window.  Do the `aws configure` step to make sure the Windows AWS CLI is installed and working, and that your *Windows* `.aws` directory is created and populated with files.
3. `cd` around into your Cygwin home directory, but still in the CMD.EXE window.
4. If you have a `.aws` in your Cygwin $HOME, delete it or move it out of the way.
5. `mklink /j .aws %USERPROFILE%\.aws`   This creates an *NTFS directory junction*, which is halfway between a Unix hard link and a Unix symbolic link, works only for directories, and -- unfortunately -- is a built-in command to CMD.EXE, not an external binary of its own.  This makes a sort-of-directory named `.aws` in your Cygwin $HOME, linked to your Windows "home".  (This command is why you had to run CMD.EXE.  There's probably a way to do it inside of PowerShell, and I don't care.)
6. Type `dir` to see that the `.aws` junction exists and how CMD.EXE displays it.
7. Exit CMD.EXE and wash your hands thoroughly with soap.  You won't need to touch that again.
8. Start a Cygwin shell, of whatever combination you prefer.  (mintty+bash, or whatever)  Run `ls -lFd .aws` to see the newly-created junction -- note how the Cygwin DLL presents directory junctions as symlinks.
9. You may need to adjust your PATH inside Cygwin to pick up the AWS CLI installation.

With the junction in place, using `aws` inside my Cygwin shell performs normally, and all tools are using the same config/credentials files, right where the (Windows) AWS CLI v2 installation expects to find them.

The one minor hitch is that AWS CLI under Windows uses CRLF newlines in all its output, so if doing any scripting with `aws [...] --output text`, you need to pipe that through `tr -d '\r'` before doing anything with the results.  Else you get the hidden carriage return stuck on the end of your lines, fouling things up at random times.  (You can pipe AWS output through `cat -A` to make them visible for debugging.)

Comment: I should also add that it's also entirely okay to create the "real" directories in your Cygwin $HOME, and create the directory junctions in your Windows %USERPROFILE%.  It mostly depends on which side needs to support special permissions or careful programmatic access by tools; make that side use the real directories.