# AWS CLI authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed aws cli on my cygwin, created a IAM user, downloaded its access key information.

in the `~/.aws/credentials` contain

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and `~/.aws/config` contain

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = text
```

But I get authentication error:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-regions
A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to get AWS command line interface to work in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809822/how-to-get-aws-command-line-interface-to-work-in-cygwin) - it claims that it looks in the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable for credentials, not ~/.aws/

Alternatively there's a windows powershell version of the CLI if that suits: http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was the problem. I copied the same `credential` and `config` files to my MacBook and worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I would check see if the $PATH is exported in ~/.bashrc correctly, if not add your the below line if not already there.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.aws"
```

To check this when you login with the user try to

```
#echo $aws_access_key_id
#echo $aws_secret_access_key
```

on the shell to confirm they are showing up the credentials.
If you cannot still get going try to add the credentials again with the command

```
#aws configure
```

Good luck, hope it helps.